# What is the best way to join 2 documents in Spring Data?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-mongo

I have 2 classes `Author` and `Book`.

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
class Person {

    @Id
    private BigInteger id;

    private String firstName;

    private String surName;

    @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    private boolean deleted;

}


@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true)
public final class Author extends Person {

    @Builder
    public Author(BigInteger id, String firstName, String surName, LocalDate dateOfBirth, String bio, boolean deleted) {
        super(id, firstName, surName, dateOfBirth, deleted);
        this.bio = bio;
    }

    private String bio;

}


@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
public final class Book {

    @Id
    private BigInteger id;

    private String title;

    @DBRef
    private Author author;

}
```

How should I deal with finding books by an author who is not deleted?
If I do this:

```
@Repository
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, BigInteger> {

    Set<Book> getByAuthor_Deleted(boolean isDeleted);

}
```

then `org.springframework.data.mapping.MappingException: Invalid path reference author.deleted! Associations can only be pointed to directly or via their id property!` exception is thrown.

Could you clarify me how can I solve this task?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This should work.

```
Book findByAuthor_IdAndAuthor_Deleted(Biginteger id, boolean isDeleted)
```

Pass id and false to this function.

Comment: No, still the same exception

Comment: change boolean to Boolean in your Author class for deleted

Comment: Still the same. Have you heard about autoboxing?

Comment: ofcourse i  know autoboxing. spring data treats certain types differently dependeing on your database typ, for example int and Integer.

Comment: Anyway I've tried it and still the same. I think I must write a @Query with $lookup

Comment: if you just do findByAuthor_Id  and pass author id does it work?

Comment: No, it works with embedded document and I need to refer to author from another collection